# How to do subset of the dataframe with value 1 in both rows and columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have the dataframe which has 900 rows and 2000 columns.The row and column have different ID names. I need to extract the value 1 from the dataframe along with the column and row names.[I have attached the sample input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggrLZ.png)
I have attached sample output
[The output should be in this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDrfZ.png)

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Try with `which(df == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple base R approach would be as follows:

```
data[data != 1] <- NA
data[rowSums(data,na.rm = TRUE) > 0, colSums(data,na.rm = TRUE) > 0]
#   A  C  D  F  H
#I  1  1  1 NA NA
#J NA  1 NA  1  1
#K NA NA NA NA  1
```

**Sample Data**:

```
data <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
3L), B = c(2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), C = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), D = c(1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L), E = c(0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), F = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
2L), G = c(2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L), H = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("I", 
"J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S"))
```